# How to Lock and un Lock in Mongodb at global, database or collection level?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I very new to Mongodb operation, I want to lock the collection/doc in new(3.x)version of mongodb, please can you anyone help me out with any example or samples.

thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks Cristy, That is ok(Explanation) I want code wise like  Example db.Collection.lock();